# Cutting polygons that overlay other polygons in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, buffer, vector-layer

I created a layer of buffer polygons following some conditions (distance from parks, stations etc). Some of the buffer polygons are now overlaying public_parks polygon layer.

What tool can I use in order to create a new layer where the buffer polygons are not covering the parks polygons?

I thought about using NOT boolean, but from what I know it works only on raster data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Erase* tool, where the INPUT is your buffer polygons layer and the ERASE FEATURE is your public_parks layer:

[image]

Image source: ArcGIS Desktop *Erase* tool window

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the Erase tool, but unfortunately I don't have the license.

However, I found a way to substitute the Erase tool using this site:

- Buffer polygon layer - merge.
- Public park polygon layer - merge.
- Union tool for both layers.
- Then, selected the record contains the buffer polygons without the parks and exported the data as a new layer.